# Finding location of a file in mapbox example code

Tags: javascript, html, json, mapbox

I am trying to replicate this example code (link below) for an interactive U.S. map: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/choropleth-joined-data-multiple-variables/

Given that I am new to HTML and Javascript, the issue that I am facing is that I don't know where should these two files be resting (or located) (1) us.geojson, and (2) censusdata.json

In the code these files are addressed as

> '/mapbox.js/assets/data/us.geojson'

and

> '/mapbox.js/assets/data/censusdata.json'

, respectively.

Would appreciate your guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the two example files from the mapbox website:

1. https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/assets/data/us.geojson
2. https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/assets/data/censusdata.json

You can save the HTML example in the same folder where you downloaded the files. Then, just update the two calls in the code to point to the location of the files on your computer:

```
$.getJSON('/folder_where_you_downloaded_me/censusdata.json')
.loadURL('/folder_where_you_downloaded_me/us.geojson')
```

Finally, you will most likely have to serve the folder containing these files -- otherwise the two function calls above will probably complain about [Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

In a terminal session, go to directory with the folder inside, and run this command:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

You will see something like

`Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...`

Then visit http://localhost:8000 (or whatever port it says it is running on) in your web browser.

If you don't have SimpleHTTPServer, just google "serving a folder locally" for your system. You don't have to use SimpleHTTPServer for it to work.

Let us know if you have any trouble getting it to work, and good luck in your HTML and JS studies.

Comment: Thanks @thmsdnnr. This was helpful. I brought changes to my index.html file (https://github.com/awahdat/vizrisk_2020/blob/master/index.html), however my webpage and map doesn't load. Can you check if I am referencing the files correctly. The us.geojson file should be fine because it is called from mapbox. I added noaaData.json to my Github and then I am calling it in my index.html.

Comment: @Hi ZiaW: I looked at your index.html and did not see a `noaaData.json` file included anywhere, though I did see it in the repo. You should be able to update the paths to these files in the code e.g., https://awahdat.github.io/vizrisk_2020/noaaData.json has the file, and I can see your index.html when I visit https://awahdat.github.io/vizrisk_2020/. I'd advise going through your code and making sure every URL exists & has the correct path. I think there are a few still to fix up.

Comment: Thanks! I finally fixed the links. Really appreciate your guide. Maps do display now, and it seems the us.geojson and noaaData.json files join as well. Moving on, my next challenge is to find out why the maps don't show choropleth colors. Right now it is one color for every state. Hopefully, I am not facing a mess :)